# How to correctly use SO_RXQ_OVFL to detect UDP overrun on a Linux socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I want to use Linux socket option SO_RXQ_OVFL to detect UDP overrun.  This option uses an ancillary message to report the number of dropped packets. From man:

```
SO_RXQ_OVFL (since Linux 2.6.33)
Indicates that an unsigned 32-bit value ancillary message (cmsg) should be     
attached to received skbs indicating the number of packets dropped by the   
socket between the last received packet and this received packet.
```

My code is not finding the ancillary message.  Here is what I do:

At startup I create the socket and specify the SO_RXQ_OVFL socket option:

```
int dropmonitor_on = 1;
if ( setsockopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RXQ_OVFL, &dropmonitor_on, sizeof(dropmonitor_on) ) != 0 )
{
    perror("setsockopt SO_RXQ_OVFL not supported by your Linux Kernel");
}
```

Then I have a receive function that calls recvmsg and looks for the ancillary message:

```
struct sockaddr_in src_addr;  // The source address will be assigned to here

struct iovec iov[1];
iov[0].iov_base=ap_rxBuffer;
iov[0].iov_len=a_maxSizeBytes-1;

int cmsg_len = CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(uint32_t));
char cmsg[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(uint32_t))];
memset(cmsg,0,cmsg_len);

struct msghdr message;
memset(&message,0,sizeof(struct msghdr));
message.msg_name=&src_addr;
message.msg_namelen=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
message.msg_iov=iov;
message.msg_iovlen=1;
message.msg_control=cmsg;
message.msg_controllen=cmsg_len;

int receivedBytes = 0;

if ( (receivedBytes = recvmsg( a_socket, &message, 0 )) == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    closeSocket(a_socket);
    fatal("recvmsg() failed");
}
else 
{
    // Reception successful so interrogate ancillary message to get number of dropped packets

    int udp_packets_dropped = 0;

    struct cmsghdr* p_cmsg;
    p_cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&message);
    for (p_cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&message); p_cmsg != NULL; p_cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&message, p_cmsg))
    {
        if ((p_cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET) && (p_cmsg->cmsg_type == SO_RXQ_OVFL))
        {
            int* p_udp_packets_dropped = (int *) CMSG_DATA(p_cmsg);
            udp_packets_dropped = *p_udp_packets_dropped;
            cout << "UDP pkts dropped: " << udp_packets_dropped << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (p_cmsg == NULL)
    {
        fatal("Error: p_cmsg == NULL");
    }
}
```

When I run the code it stops with this fatal error:

```
Error: p_cmsg == NULL
```

which is generated by the above code and indicates that no ancillary message was found.  Strangely, sometimes I do get an ancillary message so perhaps I have left something uninitialized.

I have checked the code carefully but can see nothing wrong. I would be grateful for some help please.

Answer (score 3):

I also have this issue.

After some dig, I found some hints in the kernel source code:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c

```
static inline void sock_recv_drops(struct msghdr *msg, struct sock *sk,
                   struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (sock_flag(sk, SOCK_RXQ_OVFL) && skb && SOCK_SKB_CB(skb)->dropcount)
        put_cmsg(msg, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RXQ_OVFL,
            sizeof(__u32), &SOCK_SKB_CB(skb)->dropcount);
}
```

Look at the "if (... && SOCK_SKB_CB(skb)->dropcount)", I think if the dropcount is 0, the cmsg should be empty. Your code should be correct.

Comment: I wrote some testing codes and now I can sure about it. I also found that the value in SOCK_SKB_CB(skb)->dropcount will not reset after recvmsg. When I read the kernel code I was full of curiosity why I can not find the somewhere reset the value. That is, if the value is not zero, you will keep recv the value in cmsg.

Comment: For me this is working sometimes and sometimes not. I am sure that there are drops because I can open /proc/<pid>/net/udp and see there the correct number. I don't know why, maybe the kernel updates dropcount after the recvmsg call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending packets with sendmsg using the same struct cmsghdr that you used for recvmsg, be aware that unlike cmsghdr control data for IP_PKTINFO, IP_TOS or IP6_TOS, the presence of SO_RXQ_OVFL message data in the cmsghdr will cause an EINVAL error when you try to send it.

If you are not setting any other options like IP_PKTINFO etc. on the recvmsg call, you can simply set msg_controllen to zero, and msg_control to NULL. If you are depending on IP_PKTINFO for sockets bound to INADDR_ANY to make sure the source IP address on a reply matches the destination IP address on the query, you will need to go through the msg_control byte data and copy only cmsg types that are supported by sendmsg.